# Construct Optimized Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel

I have this table:

Permits Table

```
id  parent_id   user_id    renewed_at
1   0           1          2019-01-01
2   0           8          2019-01-01
3   1           7          2019-01-02
4   1           2          2019-01-03
5   2           3          2019-01-02
6   0           2          2019-01-02
7   6           9          2019-01-03
8   2           2          2019-01-09
9   0           3          2019-01-10
10  9           2          2019-01-11
11  9           5          2019-01-12
```

The permits undergoes on renewal indicated on the `parent_id` column.

The thing is the permit can be renewed by different persons indicated on `user_id` field. A user can be considered as the owner of the permit if he is the latest one who made the renewal.

How to construct an optimized eloquent query that will get all permit that was owned by a specific person, for example = user with id number 2

What I did is:

1. Get all latest record
2. Filter the result from step 1 if user_id=2

The problem here is that this table has 100K rows making my query very expensive.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
$records_raw = Permits::groupBy('parent_id')
    ->where('parent_id', '>', 0)
    ->get([DB::raw('MAX(id) as id')])
    ->pluck('id');

$my_permits = Permits::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->whereIn('id', $records_raw)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Please provide your existing query.

Comment: @LimKeanPhang - please check the UPDATE 1

Comment: @kapitan renewed_at will be update manually or automatic?Mean you may insert row for ex id=8 , parent_id=2 , user_id=2 , renewed_at=2018-01-01??

Comment: @mohammadHosseini renewed_at is an automatic timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel Eloquent

for example you want the last record of user 2 (user_id=2)

```
$user_id = 2;
Permits::where('user_id',$user_id)->orderBy('renewed_at','desc')->first();
```

it takes the latest record added for user_id=2.....means record 8

```
8   2           2          2019-01-09
```

this is optimize query and not expensive

Update:

```
    $user_id = 2;
Permits::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('parent_id','!=',0)->orderBy('renewed_at','desc')->get();
```

This will return what you want

hope this is helpfull

Comment: if you use user=2, you should get row 4 and row 8.

Comment: thank you for your time, i have added rows 9-11. based on your updated answer, row 9 will also be selected. row 9 shouldn't be selected because user id number 2 is not the latest owner of that permit, it is now user id number 9.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use a query cache and recommend to profile your queries Using

DebbugBar ->https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Thanks and i hope to be a helpful comment